# Sorting Google Sheet by multiple criteria with script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some data that I need to sort, first by date, then by ID. So basically I want to group all the IDs together, but have those individual groups sorted by date so that the groups with the earliest dates appear first. This is the code I'm using:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
sheet.getRange("A1:C").sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}, {column: 3, ascending: true}]);
```

However, it seems to only be sorting by date and that's it. [Here's a sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UjbsfGR_Rms55nz7t_Nc_JU87xDhmohiuQlJCByfIT8/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, in your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sheet.getRange("A1:C").sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}, {column: 3, ascending: true}]);
```

#### To:

```
sheet.getRange("A1:C").sort([{column: 3, ascending: true}, {column: 1, ascending: true}]);
```

Comment: That groups together the IDs like it should, and sorts by date within the groups of IDs, but it doesn't sort those groups of IDs by date, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Craig Thank you for replying. About `That groups together the IDs like it should, and sorts by date within the groups of IDs, but it doesn't sort those groups of IDs by date, if that makes sense.`, in this case, can you include your expected situation in your sample Spreadsheet? By correctly confirming your expected situation, I would like to modify my answer. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = sheet.getRange("A1:C" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var dates = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  var dummyRange = sheet.getRange(1, 5, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  var newDate = [];

  dates.forEach(function (date) {
    newDate.push([date[0].slice(0, 10)]);
  })

  sheet.getRange(1, 5, newDate.length).setValues(newDate);
  sheet.getRange("E1:G").sort([{ column: 5, ascending: true }, { column: 7, ascending: true }])
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Explanation:**

The reason it only sorts by date is because in your sample data you have time included which also includes it in the sort so it just makes sense that they are sorted that way since there really are no equal values.

A workaround would be to cut only the date from the value and use it for sorting. Using the [.slice()](https://codingbeautydev.com/blog/javascript-get-first-n-characters-of-string/#:%7E:text=slice()%20Method-,To%20get%20the%20first%20N%20characters%20of%20a%20string%20in,first%202%20characters%20of%20str%20.) to get the first N characters. In your sample you can use `date[0].slice(0, 10)` to get only the date.

In my sample code I have set the updated values to a different range and used it for sorting.